# how to create multiple checkboxes in wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create my own wordpress widget plugin for woocommerce products. so i had some coding but stuck with the issue of storing the checked/selected categories.

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'select_product_categories' => '' ));

    $args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => true );
    $show_pcategories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

    $title = strip_tags( $instance['title'] );               
    $select_product_categories = $instance['select_product_categories'];

    <?php /* Select Categories Checkbox to display */ ?>
    <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'select_product_categories' ); ?>">Select Product Category to display:</label><br>
    <?php                    
        foreach( $show_pcategories as $category ) {
        ?>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('select_product_categories') . $category->term_id; ?>"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('select_product_categories') . $category->term_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('select_product_categories'); ?>[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $category->name; ?>" <?php checked('1', $category->name); ?> /><?php echo $category->name; ?></label><br>
        <?php
        }
}
```

its extracting all product categories of woocommerce but when i check some category and saving ... its not working :(

kindly help me guys

=====================================

**SOLUTION**

i just tried and it working fine now!

```
foreach( $show_pcategories as $category ) {
?>
    <label><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'select_product_categories' ) . $category->term_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('select_product_categories'); ?>[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>" <?php foreach ( $select_product_categories as $checked ) { checked( $checked, $category->term_id, true ); } ?>><?php echo $category->name; ?></label><br>
<?php
}
```

I used foreach loop for validating ... and also define the variable an array

$select_product_categories = (array) $instance['select_product_categories'];

Comment: How are you saving the values in the DB ? If you're having trouble finding out whether a checkbox has been checked or not, you have two possible solutions : 1/ `$_POST['x']` is set if and only if the checkbox `x` has been checked. 2/ for each checkbox named `x`, you add a `hidden` field also named `x` with a default value. If the checkbox `x` has not been checked, then you will receive the default value in `$_POST['x']`.

Comment: sorry to say! but i don't understand!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand what you problem is.

If you problem is that you have trouble finding out which checkboxes have been checked, and which one have not, here are two solutions :

**1st solution : Use `isset()`**

Say in your form you have this checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="value1" /> Check me !
```

Once the form has been submitted, in your PHP code, you can do :

```
$checked = isset($_POST['check1'])
```

The variable `$checked` will be true if the user checked the checkbox `check1`. (Beware, it does not mean that its value is `value1`)

If the user has not checked the checkbox `check1`, then doing `var_dump($_POST['check1'])` would report an error `undefined index` : `$_POST['check1']` does not exist.

**2nd solution : Add a `hidden` field**

You can also add a `hidden` field named just like your checkbox, that will act as a default value :

```
<input type="hidden" name="check2" value="default value" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="value2" /> Check me !
```

Once the form has been submitted, you can access in your PHP code to `$_POST['check2']`, which will be equal to `default value` if the user has not checked the checkbox `check2`, and equal to `value2` if he checked it.

Please note that even with the second solution, `$_POST['check2']` may not be defined. **Never trust your inputs.**